# I got error message "Error: 403 Cloud IAM permission 'cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict' denied."

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-translate

I tried to use Google Cloud Translate (advanced) API but failed...

It keeps showing me the error message. "Error: 403 Cloud IAM permission 'cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict' denied."

Here is my code. Please look over it and tell me the way to resolve the issue... ;(

I granted the permission on my account.
(owner, API key manager, Cloud Translation API Manager)

But still doesn't work properly.

```
from google.cloud import translate_v3 as translate
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    './static/myauth-xxxxxx.json')

project_id = "myid"
source_language_code = "fr"
target_language_code = "en"  
excel_file_path = "testfile/test2.xlsx"

client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()


location = "us-central1"
parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"

def translate_cell(text):
  """Translates a single cell of text."""
  request = {
      "parent": parent,  
      "contents": text,  
      "source_language_code" : source_language_code,
      "target_language_code": target_language_code,
  }
  try:
    response = client.translate_text(request=request)
    # Print a message
    print(f"Excel file translated to {target_language_code}.")
    return response.translations[0].translated_text
  except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error translating cell: {text}. Error: {e}")
    return text  # Return original text in case of error

# Load the Excel workbook
workbook = load_workbook(excel_file_path)

# Iterate through sheets and cells
for sheet in workbook.worksheets:
  for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2): 
    for cell in row:
      if cell.value: 
        original_text = cell.value
        translated_text = translate_cell(original_text)
        cell.value = translated_text 


I searched on google and granted the Cloud Translation API Admin permission on my account but still...


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDqYt.png
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PERMISSION\_DENIED: Cloud IAM permission 'cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict' denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517543/permission-denied-cloud-iam-permission-cloudtranslate-generalmodels-predict-d)

Comment: Not work. I already saw that post and granted the role on my account...